# lib/screens/chat_screen.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html' import 'dart:html';

Tags: dart, dart-html

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Text('This works'),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          Firestore.instance
              .collection('chats/N9acVSfO3LcRNce99UMQ/messages')
              .snapshots()
              .listen((data) {
            data.documents.forEach((element) {
              print(data.documents[0]['text']);
            });
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

lib/screens/chat_screen.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
^
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=
org-dartlang-
untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri  (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:33:7)
#1      asFileUri  (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:659:37)

#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.
dart:853:21)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not import web-only libraries in code that is supposed to run in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
data.documents.forEach((element) {
          print(data.documents[0]['text']);
        }
```

or

```
data.documents.forEach((element) {
          print(data.element[0]['text']);
        }
```

to use element instead of documents.